# Download revit file from a360 forge bucket

Tags: oauth, autodesk, revit, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

How can I download a file from an Autodesk A360 bucket that I created? The file is a Revit project file and I used 2-legged OAuth for authorization.

Comment: Oh and i need to do this in a winform if possible!

Comment: and did i mention C# would be nice, i just found out about json the other night, the one without the mask and now i am wondering if this is essential to get the handle of my project from the forge cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 3 legged authentication to access files from A360, because you need the approval of the user whose account you are accessing - the user is the 3rd leg.
If you are trying to access files from your own application's private bucket on OSS then you do not need a user's approval because the bucket belongs to your app and not a user.

As a side note, in case of trying to access BIM 360 files (in case that's what you are talking about) using the Data Management API, then for the time being you need to use 2 legged authentication but your app needs to be manually approved by us.

2-legged vs 3-legged authentication is covered by Augusto's webcast:
[Introduction to oAuth and Data Management API](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/09/introduction-to-oauth-and-data-management-api.html)

Comment: Hi Philippe, I used the tuturial here to upload to ....? http://the360view.typepad.com/blog/2015/02/autodesk-view-and-data-api-intro-overview.html

Comment: Where my buckets and their contents are I am not completely sure now. I thought it was a360 that was accepting my uploads to. The above link to the oauth 2 legged and create a bucket and upload tutorial. I am only looking initially to store files for collaboration and upload/ download through a winform with .net

Comment: yes, after watching Augusto's tutorial I think I have upload rvt files sucsessfully to a bucket in the OSS. Here is what I am attempting to do. In my .net winform upload a file into a project named bucket transparently signing in with no login and hence 2-legged.  The user than can select a project and download any files in that bucket or get a list of files from that bucket and download again all in the same winform

Comment: public static void Download(string accessToken, string bucketName, string fileName, byte[] fileData)
        {
            // (1) Build request 
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(baseApiUrl);

            // Set resource/end point
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "oss/{version}/buckets/{bucketname}/objects/{filename}";
            request.Method = Method.GET;

        }

Comment: So can I use Method.Get, to retrieve a Uniform Resource Name (URN) to download the .rvt file that i uploaded?

Comment: Also what is the file size limit for upload and then download from the object storage service?

Comment: public static void Download(string accessToken, string bucketName, string fileName, string strPath)
        {
            // (1) Build request 
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(baseApiUrl);


            // Set resource/end point
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Resource = "oss/{version}/buckets/{bucketname}/objects/{filename}";
            request.Method = Method.GET;
            

            client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(@"G:\" + fileName);

        }

Comment: I tried the above to download the file at the bucket I uploaded to from the same application. What I really download is a text file, if you change the extension, it says service unavailable.

Comment: oops spoke to soon i forgot the token! now i need to get something worthwhile for coordination up there

Comment: Are you all set then? There is no file size limit on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a bucket key after attempting to create a bucket in when i change v1 to v2...

see below

public static string GetBucket(string accessToken, string bucketKey, string policy)
        {

```
        // (1) Build request 
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(baseApiUrl);

        // Set resource/end point
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "oss/v1/buckets";
        request.Method = Method.GET;


        // Add headers  
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // MH: skipping this works. 

        // Add JSON body. in simplest form. 
        request.AddJsonBody(new { bucketKey = bucketKey, policy = policy });


        // (2) Execute request and get response
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        //TaskDialog.Show("create bucket", response.StatusDescription);

        // Save response. This is to see the response for our learning.
        m_lastResponse = response;

        TaskDialog.Show("response", m_lastResponse.ToString());

        // Get the key = bucket name 
        string key = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            OssBucketsResponse bucketsResponse = deserial.Deserialize<OssBucketsResponse>(response);
            key = bucketsResponse.key;
        }




        return key; // the bucket name 
    }
```

Comment: There are changes between the responses coming from v1 and v2 API. So I guess the deserialization will fail with the old object of OssBucketsResponse. The best thing would be if you used a tool like Postman to check what exact response you get back with the various API's and modify the code and declared classes in it accordingly.